# Will the UK replace its banknotes and coins now there is a new monarch?

Tags: united-kingdom, currency

All [sterling coins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coins_of_the_pound_sterling) in circulation and most [sterling banknotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banknotes_of_the_pound_sterling) have a picture of the late Queen Elizabeth II. Will they be replaced by ones with pictures of King Charles III?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### Yes, but not quickly

New designs of coins and notes from now on will have Charles' picture, but existing designs of coins will continue to circulate until they are withdrawn as worn out.

Notes will be replaced faster than coins. The UK issues new note designs fairly often and withdraws the old ones, as an anti-counterfeiting measure: the very slowly-changing designs of US money are surprising to the British.

The oldest note design circulating in 2022 was first issued in 2007; all the older designs have been withdrawn, although any ones that people still have can be exchanged for current issues at face value. Elizabeth II notes will probably all be replaced within a couple of decades. If we were still using paper notes, the process would be faster, but polymer notes were introduced because they last longer.

Coins last *considerably* longer: the oldest ones in circulation are from 1971. That's important, because the coinage was redesigned when the UK switched that year from 20 shillings (240 old pennies) to the pound, to the decimal standard of 100 new pence to the pound.

The first designs of Charles III notes have now been [unveiled](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-64026683). They're much the same as Elizabeth II ones, apart from the portraits. The BBC reports:

> The Bank of England said that, following guidance from the Royal household, the new notes would only be printed to replace worn notes or to meet increased demand, in order to minimise the environmental and financial impact of the change.

Charles III fifty pence pieces are already circulating. There's a picture of one at the link.

### Money from past monarchs is normal

All of the money in circulation as of the death of Elizabeth II had her portrait, because she reigned for 70 years and because of the decimalisation redesign. When I was a child learning to recognise and count money at the end of the 1960s, George VI coins were absolutely routine, and George V ones weren't rare, although they were often very worn. At the time, George VI had only been dead for about 17 years, and George V for 34. But that was 53 years ago (as of 2022). There wasn't much Edward VIII coinage issued, and I've never seen any. The combination of the long reign just completed and decimalisation has created a historically unusual situation.

Given Charles' age, it is perfectly possible that there will still be some Elizabeth II money in circulation when William succeeds him.

Comment: This answer disagrees with articles I've seen recently.  What are your sources?

Comment: @phoog It's plausible this answer isn't in disagreement with your other sources, but is using a different definition of "replace". Unlike some other countries, the UK limits the series of banknote which can be free negotiated, so all notes eventually come out of circulation as new ones are issued. Old notes can still be exchanged at their printed value, but only via limited routes (in some cases, literally at the bank of England).

Comment: @phoog in terms of old coins remaining in ciculation, it appears that crowns (face value 5 shillings/25p) from as far back as 1818 are still legal tender for debts up to £10 https://www.royalmint.com/help/coinage-faqs/how-can-i-dispose-of-commemorative-crowns/ https://www.royalmint.com/faqs/uk-currency/what-are-the-legal-tender-amounts-acceptable-for-the-united-kingdom-coins/

Comment: I kept some of my first pocket money from 1969-70 rather than changing it at decimalisation, and there were still some very late and badly worn Victoria examples in it.

Comment: @phoog What are `your` sources for the articles which disagree with the answer? Certainly in the 70's, I was seeing pre EII coinage

Comment: @Bib I was wondering when someone was going to ask that ;-)  [Cash, stamps and flags: how royal symbols will now change](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2022/sep/08/queen-death-cash-stamps-flags) "replacing [banknotes] is likely to take at least two years," but with coins it happens "organically rather than through recall."  So the disagreement is on notes, not coins.  Also, interestingly, "...in 1952, the monarch was not featured on the banknotes."  This started in 1960.

Comment: @Bib yes, and those denominations (1s and 2s) might still be circulating now if their equivalents (5p and 10p) hadn't shrunk in the early 90s

Comment: @phoog That article does agree with this answer. As to whether it will take a few years for notes to change over remains to be seen since the latest versions are far more robust. The old paper notes did not last much longer than 5 years so the normal recycling of them occurred far quicker.

Comment: @Bib while "within a couple of decades" and "at least two years" are consistent on the surface, one implies organic replacement while the other implies an active effort to recall and replace the existing notes.  However, re-reading that article for the third time, I am increasingly struck by the possibility, indeed the likelihood, that the idea of a replacement campaign is entirely a misguided assumption on the part of the reporter, who seems to have come up with the 2-year figure by analogy with the introduction of the plastic £50 note, which is not really a comparable event.

Comment: @phoog Yeah, the articale talks specifically about the replacement of the old paper/cotton notes with polymer notes (as happened with the other denominations). There is/was a concerted effort to replace these old notes specifically. I wouldn't be surprised if they just release new designs to replace notes taken out of circulation and don't specifically recall the QEII design notes.

Comment: Around 1963 our teacher asked to find pennies with as many monarchs as we could. I found 5 - Victoria (very worn), Edward VII, George V, George VI, and Elizabeth II.

Comment: @phuzi Yes, UK paper notes cease to be valid *this month* because of their replacement with the more robust polymer notes. UK currency withdrawals happen because of wear or replacements due to improved counterfeiting measures but not because the need for pictures of a different monarch. No previous notes or coins were replaced because the monarch pictures went out of date.

Comment: Only the 1d (0.41666...p) and 3d (1.25p) coins were demonitized during decimalisation.  The 6d (2.5p) stuck around until 1980.  The shilling (5p) and florin/two-shilling (10p) pieces still have direct equivalents in the new system, and (as @ChrisH noted) remained in circulation until 1990 and 1993, when they were replaced with physically smaller coins due to increased metal prices.

Comment: @dan04 I'm too young to remember the old sixpence being in use, but do recall having 1 and 2 shilling coins with their decimal value

Comment: Note that they don't just do this when there's a new monarch.  Even during her reign, the image of Elizabeth II on the coinage was updated every decade or so.  You can see she looks much younger on coins minted in the 60's vs. those minted more recently.  This is not just in the UK, of course.  You can see the same on e.g. Canadian money, and everywhere else that still keeps the British monarch on their currency.

Comment: @matt_black Note that only one monarch has ever appeared as UK notes (as monarch of the UK - Robert the Bruce appeared on one series of notes as a historical figure).  The monarch's image only started appearing in the early 60's.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Yes indeed, but coins have always had them.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica: Wikipedia [suggests otherwise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banknotes_of_the_pound_sterling#History): "Elizabeth II was not the first British monarch to have her face on UK banknotes. George II, George III and George IV appeared on early Royal Bank of Scotland notes and George V appeared on 10/– and £1 notes issued by the British Treasury between 1914 and 1928. However, prior to [...] 1960, Bank of England banknotes generally did not depict the monarch. Today, notes issued by Scottish and Northern Irish banks do not depict the monarch."

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff Damn, out pedanted.  "only one monarch has ever appeared on Bank of England notes (as monarch)" would have been correct.

Comment: I do remember reading that Edward VIII coins never reached circulation at all as he abdicated before it could and then they were quietly melted down or something. Significant, because of the anecdote that he wanted his face to point the ‘wrong’ way according to tradition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there will be a process to change the currency but it will not be a quick one. I found an article on CNN.com which talks about the process and it seems that they will be releasing new currency with King Charles III but the existing currency with Queen Elizabeth II will still remain legal currency for the time beaing.

I have quoted various paragraphs from the article that give history on recent changes and what we have heard about the upcoming changes.

[There are more than 4.7 million banknotes in the UK with the queen’s face on them. They will all be replaced](https://www.cnn.com/2022/09/09/business/queen-banknotes-and-coins/index.html)

> But now, the Bank of England, which prints the country’s banknotes, and the Royal Mint, which makes its coins, face the sizeable task of withdrawing that currency from circulation and replacing it with money bearing the portrait of King Charles III.

> There are more than 4.7 million banknotes in circulation in the UK, worth a collective £82 billion ($95 billion), according to the central bank. There are also around 29 billion coins circulating, the Royal Mint said.

> The new money is likely to introduced gradually, and coexist as legal tender with the old notes and coins for a period of time.

> A similar phase-in happened in 2017, when the Royal Mint began issuing a new 12-sided £1 coin. The new coin circulated at the same time as the old round-shaped £1 for six months before the latter lost its status as legal tender.

No changes yet

> The Royal Mint said in a statement on its website that coins bearing the image of the Queen “remain legal tender and in circulation,” and that their production would continue as usual during “this period of respectful mourning.”

> “Current banknotes featuring the image of Her Majesty The Queen will continue to be legal tender,” it said in a Thursday statement. (At one point Friday, so many people were attempting to access the Royal Mint’s website that there was a virtual queue to get in.)

Comment: The estimate of the number of banknotes in circulation in the quoted artcle is wrong by a factor of 1,000. The number is 4.7 billion not million (total value ~£80bn). And the article is wrong on many other points: there is no plan to replace current notes or mailboxes except because they wear out. We still have, for example, Victorian Mail boxes and, in periods where coins were not being redesigned, lived with multiple royal portraits on them for long periods.

Comment: @matt_black Do you have a source for that claim? I can only go by the information that I have seen. It isn't very helpful to make a claim that something is wrong but provide no evidence so that the errors can be corrected.

Comment: @JoeW Personal experience from the 60's was that Victorian pennies were not _that_ rare.  As to Victorian mailboxes, one just needs to look around in the centre of a large town.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica What does an answer talking about money on a question about money have to do with mail boxes?

Comment: @matt_black I also notice you are talking about mail boxes which is not being addressed at all in my answer or asked at all in the question so not sure how that is relevant at all.

Comment: @JoeW I was trying to add evidence for as many claims in matt_black's comment as I had evidence for.  It wasn't clear which of the several claims you were asking for evidence for.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica I was looking for the source of his claims, personal experience doesn't help someone get the data they need to correct something that is wrong.

Comment: @JoeW This is not Wikipedia.  Personal experience is allowed.  (A link to an official website may carry more weight of course.)

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica How does personal experience help me correct any issues with my answer? Your experience could be that something isn't rare but in reality it actually is.

Comment: Note that in addition to the Bank of England notes, there are three Scottish banks which issue their own notes - the Bank of Scotland, the Royal Bank of Scotland and the Clydesdale Bank. These do not bear the face of the monarch so will not need to be replaced other than through the normal wear-and-tear process.

Comment: @GordonD - any from Northern Ireland?

Comment: @GordonD The article I provided is about the Bank of England so I am not sure why the other banks matter.

Comment: Anyone who has lived in the UK during the pre-decimal era up to Spring 1971 and was of an age to notice details of coins will testify that coins from Victoria all the way to Elizabeth were a daily reality. Not so many Edward VII, LOTS of George V, never in my own experience Edward VIII (the Nazi) plenty of George VI.

Comment: @JoeW The original question was about the UK so I was pointing out that not all of its banknotes will need to be replaced.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, Northern Ireland has its own banknotes too but I'm not familiar with what's on them. And as for Edward VIII coins - they were never issued. They may have minted a few test shots but he abdicated before they went into mass production, unlike the stamps which are relatively common.

Comment: @GordonD - pictures of people or places connected with Northern Ireland, mainly. In 2006, Ulster Bank issued one million £5 notes commemorating the first anniversary of the death of the footballer George Best. The entire issue was taken by collectors within hours of becoming available in bank branches

Comment: @JoeW The source is the [Bank of England website](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/banknotes) (clearly misquoted by your source as were some other facts from it). I may have mentioned post boxes because of another question claiming they would be replaced which is false for the same reasons coins won't be.

Comment: @matt_black This question and my answer didn't mention them at all so what other question/answer claims is irrelevant. I will review what you linked but you are making it very hard to find out what you claim is wrong. Actually looking at your link I can't find any of the quotes that you say are wrong.